# session_start() for all subdomains and localhost

Tags: php, session

I have used `session_start()` function for initializing session. But the session variables were not shared across subdomains, so I had different sessions for `example.com` and `www.example.com`. So now I'm using this custom function:

```
function my_session_start() {
    $currentCookieParams = session_get_cookie_params();
    $rootDomain = ".example.com";
    session_set_cookie_params(
        $currentCookieParams["lifetime"], 
        $currentCookieParams["path"], 
        $rootDomain, 
        $currentCookieParams["secure"], 
        $currentCookieParams["httponly"] 
    ); 
    session_name("project_name_session");
    session_start();
}
```

It works fine on the production server, but it doesn't work when debugging on localhost. So I added these lines after first `$rootDomain` declaration:

```
if( $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] == "127.0.0.1" ) {
    $rootDomain = "127.0.0.1";
}
```

Now it works when I access `http://127.0.0.1/project_direcotory`. But when I access `http://localhost/project_direcotory` id doesn't. The value of `$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']` when accessing via `localhost` is `::1`, which seems like ipv6 equivalent for 127.0.0.1, but when I added `||  $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] == "::1"` to the condition and then set `$rootDomain` to `"127.0.0.1"` or `"::1"` nothing happens.

I would also like if it worked as well for local IP address, like `192.168.1.100` when accessing from other machine on the same network.

It will be also nice if the value of `$rootDomain` was not hardcoded, but was derived for example from `$_SERVER` variables.

**Is there a way for having same session for all subdomains, which would also work for all equivalents of localhost?**

Comment: Take a look at: ini_set('session.cookie_domain', '.'.yourdomain); Remember about the dot, so Your session is visible for all subdomains also. Not sure if this will be sufficient, but it is worth to look at :). BR.

Answer (score 0):

You can set a session name before calling session_set_cookie_params():

```
$some_name = session_name("some_name");
session_set_cookie_params(0, '/', '.some_domain.com');
session_start();
```

**OR**

Assuming you have an init file that you include at the top of every PHP page, you can use the `ini_set()` function. Just add this to the top of your initial page:

```
ini_set('session.cookie_domain', substr($_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'], strpos($_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'],"."), 100));
```